# What can be causing "kill -9" to not work as expected some times?

Tags: unix, sh, kill

I have created a bash script to kill some processes that are left alive after having run the shutdown scripts.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Alive processes on" `date` ":" > $LOG_DIR/roguePs.out
ps auxww | grep 'fr_home' | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v 'stopAll.sh' >> $LOG_DIR/roguePs.out
kill -9 $(ps axww | grep 'fr_home' | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v 'stopAll.sh' | cut -d " " -f 2)
sleep 10
echo "Alive processes on" `date` ":" >> $LOG_DIR/roguePs.out
ps auxww | grep 'fr_home' | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v 'stopAll.sh' >> $LOG_DIR/roguePs.out
```

In short, the above script:

- Lists any processes that contain string "fr_home", excluding the one listing the processes and the script itself (stopAll.sh)
- Kills any process found
- Lists the processes left alive after the kill

So, the script is using "kill -9" and sometimes successfully kills everything, but there have been some occasions when one process is left alive.

The output file shows something like:

```
Alive processes on Sat May 4 12:54:15 2019 :
...
<other processes>
...
oracle  6066  0.0  0.7705128413368 ?        O   May 01  8:03 /opt/app/oracle/product/middleware/fr_home/bin/rwserver server=RptSvr_tst1 batch=yes uid=1373394053
...
<other processes>
...
Alive processes on Sat May 4 12:54:25 2019 :
oracle  6066  0.0  0.7705264421520 ?        S   May 01  8:03 /opt/app/oracle/product/middleware/fr_home/bin/rwserver server=RptSvr_tst1 batch=yes uid=1373394053
```

The process is in an "O" state (process is running in a processor) before the kill and "S" (sleeping) after. Never in a "Z" state (Zombie), which I've seen listed as a possible cause why "kill -9" might not do the job.

Also, although the processes are checked after 10 seconds, I have also manually checked it hours after, and it remains alive.

Not sure what could be causing the kill not to work, or what else to implement to ensure all processes get killed consistently.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The pid is <10000 so there are two spaces between the owner's name and the pid, so the second field is an empty string. Use `pgrep` or `pkill` instead of ps+grep+cut

Comment: Yes!... That is exactly what is happening... Thanks @Aaron. The ps+grep+cut is only listing the processes that have a 6-digit pid.

Comment: The reason I am not using pgrep or pkill is because Solaris is truncating the command (more info about this here: [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3934/how-can-i-get-a-full-process-list-in-solaris-without-truncated-lines/3942) ) and some processes get missed. If I don't find a more ellegant solution to this, I can just add a second kill with ' cut -d " " -f 3 '. Far from ideal, but I think it would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I was able to find a command that seems to work well for me.

So, here are the options evaluated:

- pgrep and pkill: It makes sense to try these commands first as they are designed to do exactly what I'm after and, in most Unix-like OS, they probably do the job. However, this option did not work for me because the command is being truncated and pkill -f 'fr_home' was missing some processes.
- Use awk instead of cut: The output thrown by ps axww is too long, so awk was throwing error messages like 'awk: record `oracle  3553  0.1 ...' too long'.
- Use gawk instead of cut: Yes, gawk (an enhanced version of awk) worked for me. So command:

```
kill -9 $(ps axww | grep 'fr_home' | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v 'stopAll.sh' | cut -d " " -f 2)
```

became:

```
kill -9 $(ps axww | grep 'fr_home' | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v 'stopAll.sh' | gawk '{print $1}')
```

Comment: So... You could avoid all the greps with a single instance of awk: `ps axww | awk '/grep|stopAll\.sh/ {next} /fr_home/ {print $1}' | xargs kill -9` ... but I think you'd be *way* better off adjusting `fr_home` or whatever launches it to record a pid file somewhere, then have your start/stop script use that instead. A start script that backgrounds something stores the pid of the most recently backgrounded process in `$!`, which can be saved to a file. Your stop script can validate the pidfile by checking what's running there before killing anything.